# Not able to translate shipping method name

Tags: shipping-methods, localisation, magento2.2.6

**Magento 2.6 Enterprise Edition**
I am not able to translate the **Shipping method** names for different languages.
It is coming from admin.

> If I change the Shipping method name for **french** or **german** it's coming
>   in **English**.
>   Can anyone suggest how to translate this?

Comment: you can change viaadmin

Comment: I am changing in admin itself but its not working

Comment: change in storeview vise and then cache clear after check it

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Thanks for the reply. I created a custom shipping method and changed the title as per store.